# inject gives throws Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, karma-jasmine

I am new to AngularJS and i try to develop an AngularJS app together with coffeescript in a testdriven way and cannot get inject to work. 
For creating the project i set it up using yeoman:

```
yo angular --coffee someapp
```

Then i created the test and the provider using

```
yo angular:provider testProvider
```

The Provider looks like this:

```
angular.module 'SomeApp'
  .provider 'someApi', ->

    # Private variables
    salutation = 'Hello'

    # Private constructor
    class Greeter
      greet: () ->
        salutation

    # Public API for configuration
    @set_salutation = (s) ->
      salutation = s 

    # Method for instantiating
    @$get = ->
      new Greeter()

    return
```

And here is the unittest for the provider i'm trying to test:

```
 someApi = {'test': 'gets assigned'}

  # load the service's module
  beforeEach () ->
    console.log('service module')
    module 'SomeApp', (someApiProvider) ->
        someApiProvider.set_salutation("Hey Guys")

  beforeEach () ->
    console.log('inject')
    inject( 
      ('_someApi_') ->
    )
    console.log('after inject')

  it 'should do something', ->
    expect(!!soeaidApi).toBe true
```

I tried different versions of the inject call like:

```
inject()

inject(
  (_someApi_) ->
      someApi = _someApi_
) 

inject((_httpBackend_) -> )
```

and many more, but i do not see the 'after inject' in the log and the output of karma stays the same:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) Service: someApi should do something FAILED
    Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string
        at assertArg ($PROJ_ROOT/angular_app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1580)
        at assertArgFn ($PROJ_ROOT/angular_app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1591)
        at annotate ($PROJ_ROOT/angular_app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3474)
        at $PROJ_ROOT/angular_app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2147
        at invoke ($PROJ_ROOT/angular_app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4163)
        at $PROJ_ROOT/angular_app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4007
        at forEach ($PROJ_ROOT/angular_app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323)
        at createInjector ($PROJ_ROOT/angular_app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4007)
        at workFn ($PROJ_ROOT/angular_app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2353)
```

But if i comment out the inject line i see the 'after inject' log (obviously).
What am i missing, do i call inject in a wrong way, and if yes how to do it right? And what does the error log mean by the 'fn' argument?

Comment: what module is "someApi" defined in. You need to define a module like angular.module("some_module"). Then you need to define someApi. Otherwise just defining it as an object wont work. Something like angular.module("some_module").factory("someApi", [function() {return ...}]) needs to be done. Then in the unit test you need to do beforeEach(module('some_module')); beforeEach(inject(function(_someApi_){}));

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, i updated my question to include the unit under test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to configure the provider right and inject all the dependencies. Here is the snippet for all of you struggling when trying to test your providers, too.

Here is the unit under test:

```
class APIObject
  constructor: (@api_url) ->

  get_something: () ->
    console.log('get_something on ' + @api_url)
    return @$http({
      'method': 'GET'
      'url': @api_url + '/something/'
    })  

  with_http: ($http) ->
    @$http = $http
    return this


someApiFunc = () ->
  current_obj = new APIObject('not configured')

  @set_api_url = (api_url) ->
    console.log('set ' + api_url)
    current_obj = new APIObject(api_url)
    return

  @$get = ($http) ->
    # inject external dependencies here (like the $http service)
    return current_obj.with_http($http)

  return


angular.module('SomeApp').provider 'someApi', someApiFunc
```

Here is the (not yet very sophisticated) test:

```
describe 'Test', ->

  beforeEach () ->
    # get mock of someApp and configure it here
    module('someApp',
           (someApiProvider) ->
             # inject the parts you need to configure here.
             # we are still in the configuration phase here
             # and someApi isnt yet created, but someApiProvider 
             # is here yet to allow us to configure the creation
             someApiProvider.set_api_url('TEST_URL')
             return
    )
    return

  service_available_to_app = {}
  $httpBackend = {}
  beforeEach () ->
    inject (someApi, _$httpBackend_) ->
        # just make the injections available to the outside world.
        # here someApi is available and configured according to
        # someApiProvider
        service_available_to_app = someApi
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_

  it 'should getSomething and use configured api_url', () ->
    $httpBackend.expectGET('TEST_URL/something/').respond(200, {'id': '1'})
    sessions = service_available_to_app.get_something()
    $httpBackend.flush()
    expect(sessions).not.toBe(undefined)

  afterEach () ->
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest()

  return
```